# Timing a Fortran multithreaded program

Tags: time, fortran, openmp, performance-testing

I have a Fortran 90 program calling a multi threaded routine. I would like to time this program from the calling routine. If I use `cpu_time()`, I end up getting the cpu_time for all the threads (8 in my case) added together and not the actual time it takes for the program to run. The `etime()` routine seems to do the same. Any idea on how I can time this program (without using a stopwatch)?

Answer (score 5):

Try `omp_get_wtime()`; see http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libgomp/omp_005fget_005fwtime.html for the signature.

Answer (score 3):

If this is a one-off thing, then I agree with larsmans, that using gprof or some other profiling is probably the way to go; but I also agree that it is *very* handy to have coarser timers in your code for timing different phases of the computation.  The best timing information you have is the stuff you actually use, and it's hard to beat stuff that's output every single tiem you run your code.

Jeremia Wilcock pointing out `omp_get_wtime()` is very useful; it's standards compliant so should work on any OpenMP compiler - <strike>but it only has second resolution, which may or may not be enough, depending on what you're doing</strike>.  **Edited**; the above was completely wrong.

Fortran90 defines `system_clock()` which can also be used on any standards-compliant compiler; the standard doesn't specify a time resolution, but gfortran it seems to be milliseconds and ifort seems to be microseconds.  I usually use it in something like this:

```
subroutine tick(t)
    integer, intent(OUT) :: t

    call system_clock(t)
end subroutine tick

! returns time in seconds from now to time described by t
real function tock(t)
    integer, intent(in) :: t
    integer :: now, clock_rate

    call system_clock(now,clock_rate)

    tock = real(now - t)/real(clock_rate)
end function tock
```

And using them:

```
call tick(calc)
! do big calculation
calctime = tock(calc)

print *,'Timing summary'
print *,'Calc: ', calctime
```

Comment: omp_get_wtime() returns seconds as a double precision number, so sub-second resolution is certainly possible. With GCC, it provides nanosecond resolution if the platform supports high-resolution timers.

Comment: Wrt system_clock, for gfortran you can use integer(kind=8) arguments, in which case it provides nanosecond (4.6, provided the OS supports it) or microsecond (older releases) resolution.

Comment: @janneb -- my mistake, you're quite right on omp_get_wtime() -- misread the docs.

Comment: I recommend using `system_clock()` with `integer(int64)` to get a higher precision counter.

Comment: Maybe it was reasonable to give answers which are OS-dependent, but:  system_clock on Windows gfortran uses QueryPerformance API, as does omp_get_wtime() for both gfortran and ifort (with recent releases only).  With ifort Windows you don't get even millisecond resolution.