# No speedup with OpenMP in DO loop

Tags: fortran, openmp, fortran90, gfortran

I am using OpenMP in a Fortran code within a numerical solver to help speed up. I have a loop within a loop, however, I'm just parallelising the inner loop, since the upper bound for the outer loop is 10 (`mnum=10`). I have written the code in the following way.

```
use omp_lib
use nuclearvars
implicit none
external speciesgenerationHe  

real(kind=dp) :: t, siaabsorption, intabsorption, vacabsorption, Heemission, &
&  Heabsorption, vacemission, Hemonomeremission, Hevacapsorption,tempdf
integer :: i,j,n,id,proc
real(kind=dp),dimension(n) :: y, ydot
...


 proc = omp_get_num_procs()-1
 do j=0,mnum

   !$omp parallel do private(i,tempdf) num_threads(proc)shared(Px,Pm,Qx,Qm,Qvarr,Qi,f,xnum,mnum,ydot,j) &
   !$omp reduction(+:vacabsorption,Heemission,Heabsorption,vacemission,siaabsorption) schedule(static)

   do i=1,xnum

     tempdf = (Px(i-1)*f(i-1,j)-Qx(i,j)*f(i,j)-Px(i)*f(i,j)+Qx(i+1,j)*f(i+1,j)) &
     & +(Pm(i)*f(i,j-1)-Qm(j)*f(i,j)-Pm(i)*f(i,j)+Qm(j+1)*f(i,j+1))

     siaabsorption=siaabsorption+Qi(i)*f(i,j)
     vacabsorption=vacabsorption+Px(i)*f(i,j)
     Heemission=Heemission+Qm(j)*f(i,j)
     Heabsorption=Heabsorption+Pm(i)*f(i,j)
     vacemission=vacemission+Qvarr(i+1,j)*f(i+1,j)

     ydot(i+4+j*xnum)=tempdf
   end do
   !$omp end parallel do
   intabsorption=intabsorption+Qi(1)*f(1,j)
   Hemonomeremission=Hemonomeremission+(Qm(j)+Qm(1))*f(1,j)
 end do
```

This increases the computation time when I test it with the `omp` lines! The inner array goes up to 100 (`xnum=100`). The computer I'm using uses an AMD E1-1200 processor (only has 2 cores/threads), so I'm not expecting much speed-up (though I'm planning on moving it up to an i5 Intel processor). I would, however, expect a little bit of speed-up compared to running it in serial?

My worry is I have not written it efficiently. I would think `omp reduction` is the best option in this case? Separating the `ydot` and the values it does the reduction on (`siaabsorption`, etc.) into separate loops makes it slower.

Comment: Are your results correct with OpenMP? How do your measurement results look like? How do you measure the time?

Comment: @Giles Why did you return the fortran tag to the title and mis-capitalized OpenMP back to openMP? Is it really necessary to edit "I am" to "I'm"?

Comment: Just two comments/questions: 1/ `proc = omp_get_num_procs()-1`: what is the value of `proc`? and 2/ `!$omp reduction`: shouldn't that be `!$omp& reduction`?

Comment: Ok, I'm just capitalizing DO to make it distinct in the title, because we have no monospace there, I hope it is acceptable to others.

Comment: There is an ever so slight change in the values calculated, but I am talking about changes after 7 decimal places and would be negligible in the final answer I use. From what I understand, slight discrepancies like this are expected? I am compiling with gfortran and optimisation flags set to -03 (high) so maybe that has an effect too. @VladimirF

Comment: @Giles the value for proc I get is 1. So it has thread 1 or 0 I think? if you make this higher, it slows down the code.

Comment: @VladimirF I time the code by using 'call cpu_time' at the start of the program, then at the end when it finishes. Then take it to be the difference between the two times.

Comment: Why don't you show it ion your code? You are wasting everyone's time. You **cannot** use `cpu_time()` for parallel programs. That is the end of the story. Use `system_clock` or `omp_get_wtime()`.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5083051/timing-a-fortran-multithreaded-program?rq=1 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28450367/why-fortran-is-slow-in-the-julia-benchmark-rand-mat-mul http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25490759/cpu-time-of-thread

Comment: Do we have a good duplicate?

Comment: You say all this but, I have tried with system_clock and it doesn't seem to make much difference. I will have a look further to see if it is down to something else.

Comment: @L.Menzies I guess omp_get_num_procs() will return 2 on your machine, so proc = 1, and only thread 0 runs with num_threads(proc)...

Comment: If you have still problems even after the change to `omp_get_wtime` edit your question with more details. Show the numbers! Show the code with the timing! Remember to use sufficiently large problem, it should take at least several seconds to complete. Isolate your program to a small self-contained example, so that everyone can run it, without using any other modules.